# Wix Burn Bootstrapper MajorUpgrade

Tags: wix, installation, burn

I use Wix 3.7 to create bootstrapped installer with custom WPF UI.

I want to implement the following use case:
1. User downloads installer for version **1** of the product and installs.
2. User downloads installer for version **2** and runs installer, which detects previous version and suggests upgrading.
3. User presses 'Upgrage' button and has the product upgraded to version 2.

I get the problem with the 3rd step. On user action I do the following:

```
_bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.UpdateReplace);
_bootstrapper.Engine.Apply(_handle);
```

in the log file located in Temp I find:

```
Plan begin, 1 packages, action: UpdateReplace  
Error 0x8000ffff: Invalid package type.
```

What does it mean "Invalid package type"? I think I've made some lame mistake obvious to more experienced Wix devs.

*Notes:*
[Repro](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58907294/eternal/Bootstrapper1.zip)
I've used `MajorUpgrade` and `Id="*"` for `Product`.
I've raised versions for both of Product and Bundle from `1.0.1.0` to `1.0.2.0`.
I have one week of Wix experience.

Comment: I have just used `LaunchAction.Install` for my bootstrapper and it has worked for updgrade scenarios.

Comment: @BryanJ Thanks, looks like when doing `LaunchAction.Install` Bootstrapper executes upgrade of my msi.

Comment: good to hear. Then I will submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just used `LaunchAction.Install` for my bootstrapper and it has worked for updgrade scenarios.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well.

Comment: I followed similar but facing problems, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854653/wix-burn-custom-boostrapper-upgrade-but-installs-side-by-side-with-older-versio